# Cannot import keras after installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda, keras

I'm trying to setup `keras` deep learning library for `Python3.5` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and use `Tensorflow` as a backend. I have `Python2.7` and `Python3.5` installed. I have installed `Anaconda` and with help of it  `Tensorflow`, `numpy`, `scipy`, `pyyaml`. Afterwards I have installed `keras` with command

> sudo python setup.py install

Although I can see `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Keras-1.1.0-py3.5.egg` directory, I cannot use `keras` library. When I try to import it in python it says

> ImportError: No module named 'keras'

I have tried to install `keras` using`pip3`, but got the same result.

What am I doing wrong? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Diagnose

If you have `pip` installed (you should have it until you use Python 3.5), list the installed Python packages, like this:

```
$ pip list | grep -i keras
Keras (1.1.0)
```

If you don’t see Keras, it means that the previous installation failed or is incomplete (this lib has this dependancies: numpy (1.11.2), PyYAML (3.12), scipy (0.18.1), six (1.10.0), and Theano (0.8.2).)

Consult the `pip.log` to see what’s wrong.

You can also display your Python path like this:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)'
['',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

Make sure the Keras library appears in the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages` path (the path is different on Ubuntu).

If not, try do uninstall it, and retry installation:

```
$ pip uninstall Keras
```

### Use a virtualenv

It’s a bad idea to use and pollute your system-wide Python. I recommend using a virtualenv (see this [guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)).

The best usage is to create a `virtualenv` directory (in your home, for instance), and store your virtualenvs in:

```
cd virtualenv/
virtualenv -p python3.5 py-keras
source py-keras/bin/activate
pip install -q -U pip setuptools wheel
```

Then install Keras:

```
pip install keras
```

You get:

```
$ pip list
Keras (1.1.0)
numpy (1.11.2)
pip (8.1.2)
PyYAML (3.12)
scipy (0.18.1)
setuptools (28.3.0)
six (1.10.0)
Theano (0.8.2)
wheel (0.30.0a0)
```

But, you also need to install extra libraries, like Tensorflow:

```
$ python -c "import keras"
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

The installation guide of TesnsorFlow is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation

Comment: Using virtual environment solved the issue! Installing libraries system-wide probably broke something. Thanks!

Comment: I ran  pip list and Keras (1.2.2)  shows up, but when I run python -c "import Keras" I still get "ImportError: No module named Keras"

Answer (score 12):

Ran to the same issue, Assuming your using anaconda3 and your using a `venv` with `>= python=3.6`:

```
python -m pip install keras
sudo python -m pip install --user tensorflow
```

Answer (score 4):

I had `pip` referring by default to pip3, which made me download the libs for python3. On the contrary I launched the shell as `python` (which opened python 2) and the library wasn't installed there obviously.

Once I matched the names pip3 -> python3, pip -> python (2) all worked.

Comment: I think that this is my issue because I was using python3 and reinstalled 2.7 because that is what my class was using.  How would I go about changing pip to work with 2.7 after it had been being used for 3?

Comment: (sorry for the late). Ideally, if you uninstall python2 + python3 and delete the folders of pip-modules 2/3 (./usr/local/lib/python2.7 + python3.5 and/or ~/.local/lib/python2.7 + python3.5) you should install things with `sudo apt-get install python python-pip python3 python3-pip`. At this point whatever you install with `pip install...` will go to `/../lib/python2.7` and will be imported when you launch the console with `python(2.7)`. Whatever you install with `pip3 install ...` will go to `/../lib/python3.5` and can be imported with `python3` console

Answer (score 0):

Firstly checked the list of installed Python packages by:

**pip list | grep -i keras**

If there is keras shown then install it by:

**pip install keras --upgrade --log ./pip-keras.log**

now check the log, if there is any pending dependencies are present, it will affect your installation. So remove dependencies and then again install it.