# ImportError: No module named 'keras' in Pycharm

Tags: python, keras

Hey guys I am currently having a problem where I am trying to do an import and I come across two problems within in my code where it says this:

```
Skip loading non-existent .env file /notebooks/app/.env
File "/notebooks/app/aime/predict/multimodal_aime_zeke_single_qs.py", line 35, in <module>
from app.aime.keras.callback.lightweight_progress_bar import LightweightProgressBar
File "/notebooks/app/aime/keras/callback/lightweight_progress_bar.py", line 5, in <module>
from keras.callbacks import Callback
ImportError: No module named 'keras'
```

And I then use this command:

```
pip list | grep -i keras
```

To realize that I do have keras listed from the command:

```
Keras (2.2.2)
Keras-Applications (1.0.4)
Keras-Preprocessing (1.0.2)
```

Can someone help please? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930952/cannot-import-keras-after-installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import keras after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930952/cannot-import-keras-after-installation)

Answer (score 1):

In `File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter` screen, You can add keras by clicking **+** sign if exists among the available packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing keras with pip3 instead of pip; this should work if you are using python3.

```
pip3 install keras
```

Also check which directory keras is installed in and make sure that Pycharm is accessing that directory.