# Keras is installed in Anaconda virtual environment but can't be imported

Tags: python, keras

I have `keras` installed into my Anaconda virtual environment but I can't import the module:

```
$ conda list | grep keras
keras                     2.2.4                    py37_1    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
keras-retinanet           0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi

$ python
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:01:00) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

What might be amiss?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930952/cannot-import-keras-after-installation Do you have installed `tensorflow`? there is a dependency problem.

Comment: Yes, `tensorflow` version 1.14 is also installed.

Comment: Is it possible that your "conda list" command is issuing some warning or other diagnostic that you are not seeing because of the " | grep keras" ? Can you "import tensorflow" ok? (I know that both of these questions are long shots, but somehow there will be a logical answer for this weird behaviour!)

Comment: I've had this issue recently, and was fixed when I restarted anaconda. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use venv for your virtual environment. For instructions:

## Mac OS & Linux: How To Setup Virtual Environment

1) After cloning the repo, `cd` into the repo and run the command: `python3 -m venv venv`

```
    This will create the virtual environment. Make sure to name it venv because the .gitignore file
    has been initialized to ignore it by default.
```

2) Activate the virtual environment by running the following command: `source venv/bin/activate`

3) To download the required packages simply run: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

```
    This will go to the requirements file that is already generated in the repo and download any dependecies.
```

4) After adding any packages, make sure to update the requirements.txt file by running: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

5) At any moment, you can run `deactivate` to leave the virtual environment.

## Windows: How To Setup Virtual Environment

1) After cloning the repo, `cd` into the repo and run the command: `python -m venv venv`

```
    This will create the virtual environment. Make sure to name it venv because the .gitignore file
    has been initialized to ignore it by default.
```

2) Activate the virtual environment by running the following command: `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

```
    To activate the virtual environment inside of a code editor's bash, run: venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

3) To download the required packages simply run: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

4) After adding any packages, make sure to update the requirements.txt file by running: `pip freeze` 
and then pasting them into the `requirements.txt` file.

5) At any moment, you can run `deactivate` to leave the virtual environment.

Finally, simply type `pip install keras`